# discord.py using `with sqlite3.connection` a bad idea?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am working on a discord.py bot using sqlite3 as my database. My current method is to have a class called `Database`, which contains a single sqlite3.connection (`.conn`). To avoid raising `database locked` errors, I am using `with db.conn:`.

My concern is that since discord.py works asynchronously instead of threading, that using this will cause the program to block. Here's what I mean:

Say I have two functions running, task1 and task2. Task1 started first and takes about 1 minute to complete. Task2 started after. They both use `with db.conn` to lock the database. Somewhere in task1, I use an await call, causing python to take a break from that function and to go through the other asynchronous functions. It gets to task2. Task2 calls `with db.conn:`, causing the single-threaded program to lock until task1 releases the lock. However, since the program is blocked in task2, it will never finish task1.

If I'm not making sense or I'm just plain wrong, sorry. My main question is, should I just use `aysncio.Lock` instead? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you should be using Async SQLite module [`aiosqlite`](https://pypi.org/project/aiosqlite/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I had no idea that existed. Does it work in the same way as sqlite, just with more async functions?

Comment: I don' know about more functions but every function is asynchronous in this the syntax is mostly the same

Comment: Ok thanks. I have one more question. I can't find the answer online, but it also doesn't seem like a good question for stackoverflow, so I was hoping you could answer it (but it's fine if you don't). Should I have one connection to my database and use it every time I need it, or should I just get a connection each time I need it?

Comment: use a new connection every time you need it and close it after your one-time work is done

Comment: ok, but doesn't that prevent me from locking the database? sorry if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You also have another module called [PostgreLite](https://github.com/AlexFlipnote/PostgresLite/tree/master) that simplifies SQL commands and also take into account asynchronous processes. Just add `postgreslite` to your requirements or do `pip install postgreslite` in your terminal.

The Github page also provides [examples](https://github.com/AlexFlipnote/PostgresLite/tree/master/examples) to understand how to use the library, additional documentation should be added soon.

As for discord.py, in your `event.py` file, I suggest you add:

```py
db = PostgresLite('database.db')
self.bot.pool = await db.connect_async()
```

in the `on_ready()` function. That way the bot object will also carry the database and you'll avoid loading it everytime you run a command.